# Распространенный причастный оборот в начале предложения — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, причастный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении (после слова "Калифорнии"):

"Расположенный на вершине холма с видом на Тихий океан и холмы центрального побережья Калифорнии(,) замок Херста является одним из наиболее знаковых особняков Америки."

Или возможны 2 варианта: с запятой или без нее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Расположенный на вершине холма с видом на Тихий океан и холмы центрального побережья Калифорнии, замок Херста является одним из наиболее знаковых особняков Америки.**

Определительный оборот обособляется в силу своей распространенности и дополнительного значения причины (отвечает на вопрос, почему замок является знаковым).

При такой структуре  факультативное обособление   становится практически обязательным, в противном случае предложение трудно прочесть.

Сравнить: Расположенный на вершине холма замок // всегда привлекает внимание туристов (нет обособления, только определительное значение).

Comment: Определительный оборот в данном случае отвечает на вопрос не "почему замок является знаковым", а " какой замок"? (расположенный на вершине холма...) Если бы предложение было бы составлено так: "Замок Херста, расположенный на вершине холма с видом на Тихий океан и холмы центрального побережья Калифорнии, является одним из наиболее знаковых особняков Америки", то здесь вопросов насчет запятых не было бы. А в данном случае считаю, что запятая нужна. Подтвердите или опровергните мое мнение.

Comment: _Arina: Сравнить: Расположенный на вершине холма замок // всегда привлекает внимание туристов (**нет обособления, только определительное значение**)._ === Но это же неправильное утверждение! И в данном случае оборот **может быть обособлен**, если автор захочет подчеркнуть его  обстоятельственный оттенок: ведь замок может привлекать внимание туристов именно из-за своего расположения. И интонация прочтения предложения при этом изменится.

Comment: @slava1947 В этом случае два решения ( авторский выбор и зависимость от контекста тоже!). Я привела это предложение  в качестве варианта, когда оборот обособлять необязательно, структура предложения допускает оба решения. А в заданном  предложении не обособить оборот нельзя, его не прочтешь без обособления.

Comment: @Алекс Это определительный оборот и, разумеется, он отвечает на вопрос КАКОЙ?  Но есть такое понятие, как актуализация оборота в препозиции путем обособления, обычно в этом случае обороту приписывается дополнительное обстоятельственное значение. Розенталь:  Распространенное или одиночное определение, стоящее непосредственно перед существительным, обособляется, если оно имеет добавочное обстоятельственное значение (причинное, условное, уступительное и т. п.):http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109 Но если оборот стоит после определяемого слова, он в большинстве случаев обособляется

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что возможен еще и третий вариант.
Если очень хочется подчеркнуть ***особое месторасположение*** знаменитого замка, почему бы не использовать тире:

**Расположенный на вершине холма — с видом на Тихий океан и холмы центрального побережья Калифорнии — замок Херста является одним из наиболее знаковых особняков Америки.**

В таком виде, думаю, предложение неплохо читается и правильно воспринимается(и "вершина холма" подчеркивается, и "знаковость особняка" не теряется).

Comment: Да, хороший вариант, а то идет нагромождение признаков,  так что и при наличии запятой предложение читается не лучшим образом (а без запятой вообще не читается)

Answer (score 0):

Если по замыслу автора причастный оборот должен иметь только определительное значение (какок замок?), то не стоит помещать его перед определяемым словом из-за громоздкости (распространенности) оборота. Запятую ставить нельзя, а без нее предложение будет трудным для восприятия.

Но если по замыслу автора причастный оборот имеет также дополнительное обстоятельное значение, то его можно поместить перед определяемым словом и отделить запятой (запятая может быть оправдана только в этом случае). При наличие запятой предложение читается нормально.

Примечание. Розенталь пишет, что для проверки наличия обстоятельственного значения используется замена определительного оборота оборотом со словом "будучи". Если можно сказать: "Будучи расположенным на вершине холма с видом на Тихий океан и холмы центрального побережья Калифорнии, замок ..." – то можно говорить о наличии обстоятельственного значения, что дает основание для обособления.

Comment: Оборот со значением пояснения или уточнения вряд ли будет находиться в начале предложения. Здесь речь идет именно о дополнительном обстоятельственном значении.

Comment: @Arina Перечитал Розенталя и понял, что должен согласиться. Это важное уточнение. Исправил ответ.